# Selenium unable to locate element even though there is not duplicate Class name

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

My code is unable to locate element on the Nordstrom rack website even though there is no duplicate class name. The element Account (after signing up) does not get recognized.

```
using NordstromRack.UI_Elements;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace NordstromRack
{
    class EntryPoint
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String parentHandle = Driver.driver.CurrentWindowHandle; // get the current window handle
            EmailSignUp signup = new EmailSignUp();
            ProfileUpdate profile = new ProfileUpdate();
            Driver.driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.nordstromrack.com/");
            Driver.driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            signup.SignUpLink.Click();

            foreach (String winHandle in Driver.driver.WindowHandles)
            {
                Driver.driver.SwitchTo().Window(winHandle);
            }
            //WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver.driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1000));
            //wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(signup.EmailInput));
            signup.EmailInput.Click();
            signup.EmailInput.SendKeys(Config.Credentials.Valid.BaseEmail);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            signup.Password.Click();
            signup.Password.SendKeys(Config.Credentials.Valid.Password);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            signup.Password.Submit();
            //signup.SignOut.Click();
            //WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver.driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1000));
            //wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(profile.Account));
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Driver.driver.SwitchTo().Window(parentHandle);
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            profile.Account.Click();**//Unable to locate this element**
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            //Driver.driver.Quit();

        }
    }
}
```

Profile.cs class details which has the account element's locator details. What am I doing wrong?
**Error thrown: Could not find element by: By.CssSelector: secondary-nav__link.secondary-nav__link--account**

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.PageObjects;

namespace NordstromRack.UI_Elements
{
    public class ProfileUpdate
    {
        public ProfileUpdate()
        {
            PageFactory.InitElements(Driver.driver, this);
        }

        [FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "input.form-label__input.form-label__input--password")]
        public IWebElement Profile { get; set; }

        [FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "secondary-nav__link.secondary-nav__link--account")]
        public IWebElement Account { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: css should start with either the tag name or "." if it's a class. And can you please let us know which html element you are trying to interact with.

Comment: <a href="/orders" class="secondary-nav__link secondary-nav__link--account"> Account</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When use Css Sector it is not necessary to give entire class name.You can give `tagname.any of the class attribute` or `.any of the class attribute`
Instead this

```
"secondary-nav__link.secondary-nav__link--account"
```

can you try that as css Selector

```
 WebElement element1=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.secondary-nav__link"));
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        action.moveToElement(element1).click().build().perform();;
```

Comment: sorry my mistake.try now

Comment: @SayaliSheode : you have use action class to click on the element.I can give you java code please change it to C#.i dont know C#

Comment: Awesome that worked! So in what cases are we supposed to use this type of notation for identification?

Comment: What can be used to identify Women in this case of HTML?    <div class="site-header__bottom">
      <div class="site-header__page-width-container site-header__page-width-container--unlocked">
        <nav class="site-header__primary-nav">
          <ul class="primary-nav primary-nav--nordstromrack">
            <li class="primary-nav__item"><a href="/category/Women" tabindex="0" class="primary-nav__link"><span class="primary-nav__item-label">Women</span></a>
              <div class="primary-nav__sub-nav">

Comment: span.primary-nav__item-label

Comment: As i mentioned in my previous  comment.tagname.any of the class attribbute.Use action class as to click on the element

Comment: And this makes sure the element identified is always unique?

Comment: You can learn from this below link how css selector use https://www.testingexcellence.com/css-selectors-selenium-webdriver/

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciate the help. I'm sure I will have some more questions psoted by the end of my Day :)